# Does renaming Windows.old folder prevent its deletion or no?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, boot, rename, windows.old

I was asked to help a person with that person's computer. The installation of Windows 10 failed for some reason, but the important files were safely put in the Windows.old folder.

The system does not boot properly, but I still have access to the command line and moved some of those files to the external USB.

In order to prevent the imminent deletion of the folder, I renamed it to SavedFiles.

Does renaming the Windows.old folder really prevent its deletion if the system does not boot at all and command line is the only way to get access to the system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the `Windows.old` will prevent its deletion.

However, you may alternatively set its conservation period to more than
the customary 28 days using
[DISM /Set-OSUninstallWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/dism-uninstallos-command-line-options?view=windows-11#set-osuninstallwindow),
up to a maximum of 60 days:

```
DISM /Online /Set-OSUninstallWindow /Value:60
```

Extending the save period might be preferable to renaming the folder,
since there are two problems with it:

1. Some files are owned by the Windows account of
   TrustedInstaller, so would be problematic to delete later on.
2. Some files are truly only symbolic links to the same files as are
   used in the `Windows` folder, so deleting them carelessly might be
   dangerous to the health of your Windows setup.

I suggest instead, in addition to extending the conservation
period to the maximum of 60 days, to copy elsewhere the files
or folders that are of interest, but leave the rest in
`Windows.old` to be cleaned up after 60 days.